# c# Windows forms checkbox text disappears when control is disabled

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a strange issue which I never noticed before.  I have a checkbox on a form whose backcolor is web:black.  My checkbox text is web:gold.
Everything is fine except when that checkbox is not enabled.  If I do

```
checkbox.Enabled = false;
```

then the text associated with that textbox doesn't show!  I never noticed this before and now I need this but can't figure out how to fix it.  Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Oh, I should mention I want it grayed out like most controls are when it's not enabled

Comment: can you show the event handler for when the checkbox checked is changed..also in design what is the value initially set at.. can you show a bit more code than just that single line..?

Comment: also do a search for `checkbox` `Ctrl+ F` and locate everywhere you are using checkbox

Comment: There is no event handler.  I just have a button and when pressed it just does a checkbox.enabled = false;  It appears that the issue is the black background color of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can respond to the control's `Paint` event to perform custom rendering. Here's an example of a custom paint method, which just draws the text as normal when the checkbox is disabled:

```
private void checkBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    if (!checkBox1.Enabled)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

        int x = ClientRectangle.X + CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(
            e.Graphics, CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal).Width + 1;
        int y = ClientRectangle.Y + 1;

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, checkbox.Text, 
            checkbox.Font, new Point(x, y), checkbox.ForeColor, 
            TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding);
    }
}
```

(The exact X and Y coordinates may need tweaking depending on your font and other rendering characteristics.)

The Paint method can be set in the Properties window for the control - it's under Appearance in the Events section. You can double-click on the empty space to create an empty event handler and take you to the code.

Comment: Hi, Yes this is a solution and works fine.  But the question remains why is this the case? It works fine if the background of the form is white but if web:black then it just disappears.  Is this just an inconsistency in .NET?

Comment: Hi @Tom. You are seeing this because the colour of the label text is not a fixed gray colour when the control is disabled; instead it's a darker version of the control's background colour (try changing the BackColor to red and you'll see the disabled text colour is a darker red). If you set the background colour to black, your label text will still be rendered, but will be black, too.